# Maginific popup is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on one website where after clicking on search icon it has to open one search window shown in image[Pop up should be look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbtyI.jpg). but in console it is showing error **index.php:113 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function(…)**

Here is my code

```
<li>
<div class="search-bar">
<div class="search">        
    <a class="play-icon popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </i> </a>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="small-dialog" class="mfp-hide">
        <div class="search-top">
            <div class="login_pop">
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="">
                    <input type="text" name="Type something..." value="Type something..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}">
                </form>
            </div>              
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
                    type: 'inline',
                    fixedContentPos: false,
                    fixedBgPos: true,
                    overflowY: 'auto',
                    closeBtnInside: true,
                    preloader: false,
                    midClick: true,
                    removalDelay: 300,
                    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
                });                                                                             
            });
        </script>               
    </div>
```

help me to get into solution.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the reference to file of `magnificPopup` plugin?

Comment: I think file path of js/jquery.magnific-popup.js not correct. Check add full path to it.

Comment: @satpal i have added reference to it . same code is working for my diffrent directory in which i have kept previous backup. i hav cross checked all the code with that fie too

Comment: @Mir i checked path is correct. after clicking on serach icon it is redirecting to #small-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Including files

```
<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: @brijiesh i have added same path <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>